# Get Serial Number of USB device with Python 3

Tags: python, usb, serial-number

I have been using pyusb to access the detail of a printer plugged in via USB. I currently have the following code working, but it appears that different devices require a different index. Here is my current code:

```
import usb

dev = usb.core.find(idProduct=0x001f)
print(usb.util.get_string(dev,256,3))

dev2 = usb.core.find(idProduct=0x0009)
print(usb.util.get_string(dev2,256,3))
```

The code for dev works perfectly, outputting a serial number, but dev2 outputs 'Zebra,' the manufacturer name. If I change 3 to either 6 or 7 it works, but then the first dev returns an error.

One solution in Python 2 is to use print(dev.serial_number), but in the serial_number attribute doesn't appear to exist in pyusb for Python 3.

Is there a way to get this working reliably for all devices? Thanks.

Comment: Solved! I simply replaced the index with 'iSerialNumber' (without quotes).

Comment: like `idProduct=iSerialNumber`?

Comment: Like this:
`usb.util.get_string(dev2,256,iSerialNumber)`.

The idProduct=0x001f is specific to the device I am accessing.

Answer (score 7):

For the present PyUSB version 1.0.2, I found the correct syntax to answer this question to be:

```
import usb

dev = usb.core.find(idProduct=0x001f)
print( usb.util.get_string( dev, dev.iSerialNumber ) )

dev2 = usb.core.find(idProduct=0x0009)
print( usb.util.get_string( dev2, dev2.iSerialNumber ) )
```