# Serial port information like manufacturer/description is unavailable on Windows but available on Linux, using node.js with serialport package

Tags: node.js, windows, serial-port, ftdi

I wrote a node.js script that connects to an external device via an USB serial port. The external device uses a chip from FTDI that converts to and from USB signals. I programmed basic device information like manufacturer, description, serial number etc. to that chip with [FT_Prog](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_124_User_Guide_For_FT_PROG.pdf), assuming this information is provided when I read the port information in my node.js script (using serialport package).
However it seems that I cannot retrieve that information on my Windows system. When I read the serial port information I am connected to, the manufacturer always is FTDI, description is `undefined`. But when using a Linux system, that information is available.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245593/how-to-find-out-what-instruments-is-behind-a-ftdi-adapter-on-windows) seems to be the same topic. But as far as I understand I should be able to get the information as soon as I programmed the chip with [FT_Prog](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_124_User_Guide_For_FT_PROG.pdf). But it's still not working.

So why is it, that I cannot retrieve this information on Windows, but on Linux?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

The code I am using:

```
'use strict';
const serialPort = require('serialport');

searchFscPort();

function searchFscPort() {
    serialPort.list().then(ports => {
        for(let i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
            if(ports[i].manufacturer == 'FTDI' || ports[i].manufacturer == 'ME') {
                console.log('Path: ', ports[i].path);
                console.log('Manufacturer: ', ports[i].manufacturer);
                console.log('SN: ', ports[i].serialNumber);
                console.log('lID: ', ports[i].locationId);
                console.log('pID: ', ports[i].productId);
                console.log('vID: ', ports[i].vendorId);
                console.log('pnpID: ', ports[i].pnpId);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Result on Windows:

```
path: COM4
manufacturer: FTDI
SN: 110
lID: undefined
pID: 6015
vID: 0403
pnpID: FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6015+110A\0000
```

Result on Linux:

```
path: /dev/ttyUSB0
manufacturer: ME
SN: 110
lID: undefined
pID: 6015
vID: 0403
pnpID: usb-ME_FSC1_7_110-if00-port0
```

This is what I have programmed into the chip:
[image]

By the way, there seems to be no node.js property to get the "Manufacturer Desc"?

Comment: It may change depending on whether it is a product of FTDI itself or a vendor's product that uses FTDI chips as parts. Please contact your hardware/device driver provider.

Comment: @kunif The chip is part of the FT-X series manufactured by FTDI itself and bought from a big European electronics vendor. The chip is then soldered by our own on the circuit board of our device. I installed the windows driver provided by FTDI, used FT_Prog to program the chip. Yet I cannot retrieve the programmed information. Even Windows device manager provides no custom information about the port.

Comment: If someone changed the firmware or configuration of the chip, wouldn't it be out of the WHQL requirements for Windows device driver authentication? Perhaps that is the reason why information cannot be obtained.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to retrieve the information?

Comment: @Quergo I added the code in the original post.

Comment: @kunif Please check the added code and result in the post. Some information is changed and apparently can be obtained correctly (like "Serial Number") without violating WHQL requirements, other (like "Manufacturer") cannot.

Comment: Perhaps the Windows device driver is telling you the manufacturer information for the .INF file. [Standard USB Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/standard-usb-identifiers), [INF Manufacturer Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-manufacturer-section) If you can see the manufacturer with a general-purpose tool such as USBView, please refer to the source code. [Windows-driver-samples/usb/usbview/](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview)