# How to read iOS device serial number or IMEI via USB ? [Windows]

Tags: python, c#, ios, wmic

I tried `pywinusb`, `wmic`, `msiout` all are unable to read the device serial number.

**msiout results**

```
Name    [00000014] Apple Mobile Device Ethernet 
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3  
Product Type    Apple Mobile Device Ethernet    
Installed   Yes 
PNP Device ID   USB\VID_05AC&PID_12AX&MI_02\6&30B6FDC3&1&XXXX   
Last Reset  19-11-2020 07:21    
Index   14  
Service Name    Netaapl 
IP Address  172.XX.XX.X, fe80::f903:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX, 2401:4900:195b:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX, 2401:4900:195b:f4e4:f903:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX    
IP Subnet   255.XXX.XXX.XXX, 64, 128, 64    
Default IP Gateway  172.XX.XX.X, fe80::XX:d1e9:XXXX:XXXX    
DHCP Enabled    Yes 
DHCP Server 172.XX.XX.X 
DHCP Lease Expires  10-12-2020 07:54    
DHCP Lease Obtained 09-12-2020 08:08    
MAC Address ‪72:70:XX:XX:XX:XX  
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\NETAAPL64.SYS (1.8.5.1, 22.50 KB (23,040 bytes), 06-05-2020 13:05)
```

How to extract this serial number?

Device Properties (sorry for not taking a screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956198/get-serial-number-of-usb-device-with-python-3 help?

Comment: No, I already tried that