# Is there a way to find a USB device's serial number using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb, usb-drive

I want to know if there is a way to find the unique device serial number of a plugged in USB device. I do NOT want the volume serial number.

My reason for wanting to do this is so that I can only make my programs work on the drives they are sold on. Some of my clients have tried copying it onto other drives and sharing them.

I do not know of any modules that can do this in Python 3.6, so if anyone could share a module that can do this or a snippet of code that gets USB device serial numbers, that would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The answer at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956198/get-serial-number-of-usb-device-with-python-3) doesn't really do anything here, as all I have gotten for my USB flash drives is "NoBackendError: No backend available." for the answer on that question. Slightly annoying, I must say. I'm not sure if the answer could be available in C# or C++ and just use cython to execute that code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Serial Number of USB device with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956198/get-serial-number-of-usb-device-with-python-3)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the code there just displayed in a traceback "NoBackendError: No backend available." But thanks for the suggestion that the question could have helped.

Comment: If we disregard the `NoBackendError` for a second, does that answer in theory achieve what you want? If so, the issue has changed from finding a suitable python package to making that package work on your machine. Back to the error, did you actually install a backend, as mentioned in the docs?

Comment: It could work, but it still doesn't for me. I've installed the backend, libusb and a driver for my USB drive, however it still shows the same error. I have provided the correct path to the backend.